# How to create custom shape widgets in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

**I have to design a menu screen in flutter as shown below, and I don't know how to create menu items with custom shapes.**

1. Food has circular icon.
2. Beverages has rounded corner box.
3. Desserts
   have rounded corner triangle slightly transformed.
4. Promotions have
   rounded corner box.

[image]

Comment: check clipPath, or you can use CustomPaint

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://shapemaker.web.app/#/) might help you or you can use CustomPainter, RotatedBox (use container and rotate with rotated Box or Transform) with Stack